# PostgreSQL query with smaller date range (result set) slower then one with bigger date range (result)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a query in postgresql, when I do the date 
BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-04' 
it's slower even though it has a smaller record set then if i do
BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-04-17'

Can any tell me why this is?

Here's for the slower query:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=9388.82..9388.88 rows=1 width=311) (actual time=187787.183..187788.001 rows=153 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9266.68..9388.77 rows=1 width=311) (actual time=8432.315..187785.091 rows=153 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: ((oh.ord_id = ord_line.ord_id) AND (iis.item_id = ord_line.item_id))"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=9266.68..9373.81 rows=1 width=333) (actual time=92.238..147161.052 rows=5847933 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: ((oh.division)::text = (item_color_cd.division)::text)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=9266.68..9373.53 rows=1 width=322) (actual time=92.214..113058.202 rows=5847933 loops=1)"
"                    Join Filter: ((oh.division)::text = (item_size_cd.division)::text)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=9266.68..9373.24 rows=1 width=312) (actual time=92.189..77932.977 rows=5847933 loops=1)"
"                          Join Filter: ((oh.division)::text = (item_class_cd.division)::text)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9266.68..9372.92 rows=1 width=294) (actual time=92.183..61183.081 rows=5847933 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=67.45..91.07 rows=1 width=75) (actual time=0.819..58.193 rows=8463 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=67.45..75.24 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.784..3.894 rows=360 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using item_dept_cd_division_key on item_dept_cd  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.045..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (((division)::text = 'BSM'::text) AND ((dept_cd)::text = 'S'::text))"
"                                                  Filter: ((dept_cd)::text ~~ 'S'::text)"
"                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on item_item_num iin  (cost=67.45..69.96 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.734..3.315 rows=360 loops=1)"
"                                                  Recheck Cond: ((iin.dept_cd_id = item_dept_cd.dept_cd_id) AND ((iin.division)::text = 'BSM'::text))"
"                                                  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=67.45..67.45 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.687..0.687 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on item_item_num_dept_id  (cost=0.00..6.92 rows=213 width=0) (actual time=0.109..0.109 rows=364 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (iin.dept_cd_id = item_dept_cd.dept_cd_id)"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on item_item_num_division_key  (cost=0.00..59.64 rows=2573 width=0) (actual time=0.544..0.544 rows=2753 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: ((iin.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using item_sku_item_num_id_key on item_sku iis  (cost=0.00..15.82 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.021..0.104 rows=24 loops=360)"
"                                            Index Cond: (iis.item_num_id = iin.item_num_id)"
"                                            Filter: ((iis.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=9199.23..9281.69 rows=8 width=66) (actual time=0.020..6.298 rows=691 loops=8463)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.01..9198.91 rows=8 width=66) (actual time=1.111..89.484 rows=691 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using ledger_demand_ix4 on ledger_demand ls  (cost=0.01..4512.71 rows=710 width=35) (actual time=1.078..79.178 rows=691 loops=1)"
"                                                  Index Cond: ((date(trans_date) >= '2012-01-01'::date) AND (date(trans_date) <= '2012-01-04'::date))"
"                                                  Filter: (((division)::text = 'BSM'::text) AND (((qty_ordered > 0) AND ((ledger_code)::text ~~ 'D%'::text)) OR ((ledger_code)::text ~~ 'DC%'::text)))"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using ord_header_pkey on ord_header oh  (cost=0.00..6.59 rows=1 width=39) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=691)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (oh.ord_id = ls.ord_id)"
"                                                  Filter: ((oh.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                                      SubPlan 1"
"                                        ->  Aggregate  (cost=10.25..10.26 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=5847933)"
"                                              ->  Index Scan using ledger_discount_ord_line_id on ledger_discount  (cost=0.00..10.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=0 loops=5847933)"
"                                                    Index Cond: (ord_line_id = $2)"
"                                                    Filter: (((ledger_code)::text ~~ 'D%'::text) AND ((division)::text = ($0)::text) AND (ord_id = $1) AND (date(trans_date) = date($3)))"
"                          ->  Index Scan using item_class_cd_pkey on item_class_cd  (cost=0.00..0.30 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=5847933)"
"                                Index Cond: (iin.class_cd_id = item_class_cd.class_cd_id)"
"                                Filter: ((item_class_cd.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using item_size_cd_pkey on item_size_cd  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=5847933)"
"                          Index Cond: (iis.size_cd_id = item_size_cd.size_cd_id)"
"                          Filter: ((item_size_cd.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using item_color_cd_pkey on item_color_cd  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=5847933)"
"                    Index Cond: (iis.color_cd_id = item_color_cd.color_cd_id)"
"                    Filter: ((item_color_cd.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"        ->  Index Scan using ord_line_pkey on ord_line  (cost=0.00..14.94 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=5847933)"
"              Index Cond: (ord_line.ord_line_id = ls.ord_line_id)"
"              Filter: ((ord_line.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"Total runtime: 187788.419 ms"
```

And for the faster query:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=395482.02..395482.08 rows=1 width=311) (actual time=3176.868..3204.741 rows=4900 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=391021.12..395481.97 rows=1 width=311) (actual time=2074.121..3151.576 rows=5118 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: ((oh.division)::text = (item_color_cd.division)::text)"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=391021.12..395481.69 rows=1 width=314) (actual time=2074.086..3113.537 rows=5118 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: ((oh.division)::text = (item_size_cd.division)::text)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=391021.12..395481.40 rows=1 width=304) (actual time=2074.067..3077.820 rows=5118 loops=1)"
"                    Join Filter: ((oh.division)::text = (item_class_cd.division)::text)"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=391021.12..395481.11 rows=1 width=286) (actual time=2074.062..3061.180 rows=5118 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((oh.ord_id = ord_line.ord_id) AND (ls.ord_line_id = ord_line.ord_line_id))"
"                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=390858.20..395310.62 rows=432 width=66) (actual time=1089.300..1596.212 rows=38947 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=92108.27..390840.92 rows=432 width=66) (actual time=603.101..1004.552 rows=38947 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ledger_demand ls  (cost=92108.27..174982.73 rows=36833 width=35) (actual time=603.076..708.321 rows=38947 loops=1)"
"                                            Recheck Cond: (((division)::text = 'BSM'::text) AND (date(trans_date) >= '2012-01-01'::date) AND (date(trans_date) <= '2012-04-17'::date))"
"                                            Filter: (((qty_ordered > 0) AND ((ledger_code)::text ~~ 'D%'::text)) OR ((ledger_code)::text ~~ 'DC%'::text))"
"                                            ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=92108.27..92108.27 rows=37705 width=0) (actual time=600.722..600.722 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ledger_demand_ix2  (cost=0.00..12712.18 rows=559935 width=0) (actual time=91.763..91.763 rows=572985 loops=1)"
"                                                        Index Cond: ((division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ledger_demand_ix4  (cost=0.00..79377.42 rows=4397941 width=0) (actual time=483.385..483.385 rows=4444914 loops=1)"
"                                                        Index Cond: ((date(trans_date) >= '2012-01-01'::date) AND (date(trans_date) <= '2012-04-17'::date))"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using ord_header_pkey on ord_header oh  (cost=0.00..5.85 rows=1 width=39) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=38947)"
"                                            Index Cond: (oh.ord_id = ls.ord_id)"
"                                            Filter: ((oh.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                                SubPlan 1"
"                                  ->  Aggregate  (cost=10.25..10.26 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=38947)"
"                                        ->  Index Scan using ledger_discount_ord_line_id on ledger_discount  (cost=0.00..10.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=38947)"
"                                              Index Cond: (ord_line_id = $2)"
"                                              Filter: (((ledger_code)::text ~~ 'D%'::text) AND ((division)::text = ($0)::text) AND (ord_id = $1) AND (date(trans_date) = date($3)))"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=162.91..162.91 rows=1 width=83) (actual time=984.452..984.452 rows=112897 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=67.45..162.91 rows=1 width=83) (actual time=0.736..852.432 rows=112897 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=67.45..91.07 rows=1 width=75) (actual time=0.705..45.978 rows=8463 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=67.45..75.24 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.675..4.358 rows=360 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using item_dept_cd_division_key on item_dept_cd  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.030..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (((division)::text = 'BSM'::text) AND ((dept_cd)::text = 'S'::text))"
"                                                        Filter: ((dept_cd)::text ~~ 'S'::text)"
"                                                  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on item_item_num iin  (cost=67.45..69.96 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.641..3.818 rows=360 loops=1)"
"                                                        Recheck Cond: ((iin.dept_cd_id = item_dept_cd.dept_cd_id) AND ((iin.division)::text = 'BSM'::text))"
"                                                        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=67.45..67.45 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.598..0.598 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on item_item_num_dept_id  (cost=0.00..6.92 rows=213 width=0) (actual time=0.089..0.089 rows=364 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Index Cond: (iin.dept_cd_id = item_dept_cd.dept_cd_id)"
"                                                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on item_item_num_division_key  (cost=0.00..59.64 rows=2573 width=0) (actual time=0.479..0.479 rows=2753 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Index Cond: ((iin.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using item_sku_item_num_id_key on item_sku iis  (cost=0.00..15.82 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.015..0.074 rows=24 loops=360)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (iis.item_num_id = iin.item_num_id)"
"                                                  Filter: ((iis.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using ord_line_item_id_idx on ord_line  (cost=0.00..71.79 rows=3 width=16) (actual time=0.009..0.072 rows=13 loops=8463)"
"                                            Index Cond: (ord_line.item_id = iis.item_id)"
"                                            Filter: ((ord_line.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using item_class_cd_pkey on item_class_cd  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=5118)"
"                          Index Cond: (iin.class_cd_id = item_class_cd.class_cd_id)"
"                          Filter: ((item_class_cd.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using item_size_cd_pkey on item_size_cd  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=5118)"
"                    Index Cond: (iis.size_cd_id = item_size_cd.size_cd_id)"
"                    Filter: ((item_size_cd.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"        ->  Index Scan using item_color_cd_pkey on item_color_cd  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=5118)"
"              Index Cond: (iis.color_cd_id = item_color_cd.color_cd_id)"
"              Filter: ((item_color_cd.division)::text = 'BSM'::text)"
"Total runtime: 3208.876 ms"
```

Query is with only change being WHERE DATE(trans_date) BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-17'

```
SELECT   trans_date                                   AS order_date,
         iin.item_num                                           AS item_num,
         color_cd                                               AS color_code,
         color_desc                                             AS color_description,
         size_cd                                                AS size_code,
         size_desc                                              AS size_description,
         class_cd                                               AS class_code,
         class_desc                                             AS class_description,
         dept_cd                                                AS dept_code,
         dept_desc                                              AS dept_description,
         Count(ord_id)                                          AS num_of_orders,
         Sum(vs.qty_ordered)                                    AS units,
         To_char(Sum(merch_amt_new3),'99G999G990.00')           AS merch_amt,
         To_char(Sum(gift_cert_new3 - gift_cert_canceled_new3),
                 '99G999G990.00') AS gift_cert,
         To_char(Sum(discount_amt),'99G999G990.00')             AS discount_amt,
         To_char(Sum(tax_amt),'99G999G990.00')                  AS tax,
         To_char(Sum(vs.qty_ordered * Coalesce(iis.cost,iin.cost)),
                 '99G999G990.00') AS extended_cost,
         To_char(Sum(merch_amt - discount_amt),'99G999G990.00') AS total,
         To_char(Sum(canceled_merch_new3),'99G999G990.00')      AS canceled_merch,
         iis.sku_id
FROM     (SELECT   oh.division,
                   oh.ord_id,
                   client_order_num,
                   source_id,
                   bus_type_id,
                   order_type_id,
                   Date(ls.trans_date) AS trans_date,
                   ls.ord_line_id,
                   Sum(ls.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered,
                   Sum(ls.amount)         AS merch_amt,
                   Sum(tax)  AS tax_amt,
                   Coalesce((SELECT Sum(ledger_discount.amount) AS SUM
                             FROM   ledger_discount
                             WHERE  ledger_discount.ledger_code ~~ 'D%'
                                    AND ledger_discount.division = oh.division
                                    AND ledger_discount.ord_id = oh.ord_id
                                    AND ledger_discount.ord_line_id = ls.ord_line_id
                                    AND Date(ledger_discount.trans_date) = Date(ls.trans_date)),
                            0.0) AS discount_amt,
                   (CASE
                      WHEN ls.ledger_code = 'DO'
                      THEN Sum(ls.amount)
                      ELSE 0.0
                    END) AS merch_amt_new3,
                   (CASE
                      WHEN ls.ledger_code = 'DOG'
                      THEN Sum(ls.amount)
                      ELSE 0.0
                    END) AS gift_cert_new3,
                   (CASE
                      WHEN ls.ledger_code = 'DCG'
                      THEN Sum(-ls.amount)
                      ELSE 0.0
                    END) AS gift_cert_canceled_new3,
                   (CASE
                      WHEN ls.ledger_code = 'DC'
                      THEN Sum(-ls.amount)
                      ELSE 0.0
                    END) AS canceled_merch_new3
          FROM     ledger_demand ls
                   JOIN ord_header oh
                     USING(division,ord_id)
          WHERE    (ls.qty_ordered > 0
                    AND ls.ledger_code ~~ 'D%')
                    OR (ls.ledger_code ~~ 'DC%')
          GROUP BY oh.division,
                   oh.ord_id,
                   client_order_num,
                   source_id,
                   bus_type_id,
                   order_type_id,
                   ls.trans_date,
                   ls.ord_line_id,
                   ls.ledger_code
                   ) AS vs
         JOIN ord_line
           USING(division,ord_id,ord_line_id)
         JOIN item_sku AS iis
           USING(division,item_id)
         JOIN item_item_num AS iin
           USING(division,item_num_id)
         LEFT JOIN item_color_cd
          USING(division,color_cd_id)
         LEFT JOIN item_size_cd
           USING(division,size_cd_id)
         LEFT JOIN item_class_cd
           USING(division,class_cd_id)
         LEFT JOIN item_dept_cd
           USING(division,dept_cd_id)
WHERE DATE(trans_date) BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-17' 
AND item_dept_cd.dept_cd LIKE 'S'
AND division = 'BSM' 
GROUP BY trans_date,
         iin.item_num,
         color_cd,
         color_desc,
         size_cd,
         size_desc,
         class_cd,
         class_desc,
         dept_cd,
         dept_desc,
         iis.sku_id
```

Comment: [explain for the first query](http://explain.depesz.com/s/qIz)  |    [explain for the second query](http://explain.depesz.com/s/qw5)

Comment: can you post the actual query, please?

Comment: I post the query in the initial question for you.

Comment: Can you try `SET enable_seqscan TO off` in a `psql` session before executing the query?

Comment: It looks like for some reason the query is not hitting some indexes.

Comment: In the first query there's a set of nested loops where the planner estimates a single row, but in fact the executer processes almost 6 million rows. The second plan also has egregious estimation errors, but only three orders of magnitude instead of 6. I suspect there's some poor statistics guiding these plans. Try running ANALYZE on all the tables involved and re-trying the queries.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL? And what about the settings for the statistics? The planner expects 1 row, but finds 5847933 rows... SHOW default_statistics_target; tells you more.

Comment: Do you think reindexing the ledger_demand table may help?

Comment: Frank Heikens - Version is 8.4 and SHOW default_statistics_target = 500

Comment: dschulz -Setting SET enable_seqscan TO off actually makes the faster query now even slower and the slower query hangs.

Comment: dbenhur - I check the tables involved in the query and they was a VACCUUM and ANALYZE ran on them today.

Comment: Just try to set enable_nestloop=off and see if it runs a little better.  Something's way off on your row estimates, and if setting default stats target high and re-analyzing doesn't fix it, you'd be best posting a test case to the postgresql-general mailing list and soliciting the core hackers to look at it and see if you've found a planner bug.

Comment: Also I just tossed the first on http://explain.depesz.com and got back: http://explain.depesz.com/s/MwR  Handy little site.

Comment: Scott Marlowe - Ok, I set enable_nestloop=off and it runs fine now.  So I will have to set this for this specific query in my code?

Comment: One other thing, I added 2 tables joins to two tables that aren't even used in my query, and it sped up the query.

Comment: Maybe I need to increase default_statistics_target from 500 or set it by column?

Comment: One other thing, when I added the 2 tables to join, the order that I added the tables in the query changed the speed of the query.  I thought that order didn't matter?

Comment: Default stats target of 500 is plenty high, if that doesn't fix the estimation problem, there's likely a bug in the query planner or a better way of writing your query that's not obvious to me.  Yes, you can enable_nestloop=off to run this query, but that's a hack, and long term what you need is the planner fixed, or a better performing query.  And if they're regular inner joins order won't matter, but for outer joins of course it will, as it changes the results.

Comment: Ok, I removed the division column from the natural joins and it sped things up.  Looks like it was an unnecessary column to include or it different have proper indexes on it?

Answer (score 4):

The short answers is that it really depends on your dataset/table/indexes etc. Try running [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) for each of your statements, it will tell you exactly what's happening.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-04'

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-04-17'
```